# Why is it allowed to have 2 identical method signatures apart from an optional parameter?

Tags: c#, language-design, optional-parameters

```
public static bool TryGetDbRow(DbConnection cnctn, string indexName = null)

public static bool TryGetDbRow(DbConnection cnctn)
```

The 1st one won't ever be called without string as last parameter.
Why is it allowed to have 2 identical method signatures apart from an optional parameter?

Comment: because C# is designed this way.

Comment: but why design that way?

Comment: because the team decided to design it in that way.

Comment: If they do not allow this then someone will ask why they do not allow us to define these two functions.

Comment: Thanks James Thorpe. @dotctor: maybe they didn't decide anything regarding this.

Comment: @dotctor As matti referred `The 1st one won't ever be called without string as last parameter.`. So nobody would ask for that.

Comment: Quoth Eric Lippert in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/09/optional-argument-corner-cases-part-one.aspx): *This was a controversial feature for the design team, which had resisted adding this feature for almost ten years despite numerous requests for it and the example of similar features in languages like C++ and Visual Basic. Though obviously convenient, the convenience comes at a pretty high price of bizarre corner cases that the compiler team definitely needs to deal with, and customers occasionally run into by accident*.

Comment: I don't think the language should protect you from foolish moves. So it's good that way. It's up to you if you write redundant code. The programmer should know what one is doing.

Comment: This is major drawback, when developer wants to add an overloaded method (2nd) to existing code -> all calls start to use that.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The quote is about why they added optional arguments, not why they made it possible to write code that "makes no sense". They could've allowed optional arguments *as well as* prevented the very case that is asked about here. There is probably a good reason though.

Comment: I'd prefer to rename the methods to make them separate. `TryGetDbRow` and `TryGetDbRowWithIndex` Much simpler and less confusing to deal with. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @matti So code changes leads to changes? Shocking.

Comment: @matti if you don't want all calls to use the overload, don't make an overload, obviously the original author made the "overload" using optional parameters.

Comment: As I said existing code is incremented by different developers and adding method number 2 breaks everything.

Comment: @Lasse, obviously I'm not in their heads, but to me the quote is more about why they did not want to add optional arguments -- because some of the design decisions that entailed were difficult to justify and comprehend. I may be wrong, though.

Comment: I think an overload should serve newly added demands. It shouldnt affect older code (without explicit intention).

Answer (score 3):

This is explained by Eric Lippert on his blog at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/16/optional-argument-corner-cases-part-three.aspx

When you create a method with optional parameters the method signature includes **all** the parameters including any optional parameters.

So in your example, these method have different signatures - the first has 2 parameters and the second has only 1. When you only have the first method, and you call the method with 1 parameter, eg

```
TryGetDbRow("connection");
```

the compiler changes it to

```
TryGetDbRow("connection", null);
```

However when you add the second method with no optional parameters, the compiler finds a match for the method with a single parameter and doesn't insert the optional parameter so the second method is called.

Optional parameters are not really optional from the method definition point of view. The compiler just applies some "syntactic sugar" to the calling code and adds in all the default values for any missing optional parameters.

Comment: You cannot object that the OP is right about the overload should serve new functionality rather than override existing one. If code compiles well and you just add a new method, it's rather unexpected the behavior to change

Comment: I'm not objecting to anything - I'm just explaining why it was done this way. In the linked blog post Eric gives an example why that had to design it this way to rewrite the calling side and not the called side. I have to admit I hadn't even considered this problem until I did some research for this question. But having read that post (and parts 1,2 and 4) it makes complete sense and I suspect now I might design my own methods and overloads a bit differently now.